# How to make a calculation and receive a result in percentage

Tags: sql

I have such an issue, I need for a column "Sales Vs Fcst" to make such a calculation: Total history / Total error and later - 1 it should give me a percentage (I need to see "%" inside of the column).

[image]

[image]

My code

```
SET ARITHABORT OFF 
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF



  SELECT f.STARTDATE AS 'STARTDATE', d.U_NPI_KEYATTRIBUTE AS 'NPIKeyAttribute', f.LOC AS 'DEMAND CHAIN', f.DMDUNIT AS 'DMDUNIT', d.DESCR AS 'Descr', CAST(f.TOTHIST as INTEGER) AS 'TOTAL HISTORY',
  f.TOTFCST AS 'TOTFCST', f.TOTFCST - f.TOTHIST AS 'TOTAL ERROR',  f.TOTHIST / (f.TOTFCST - f.TOTHIST)  - 1 AS 'Sales VS FCST' 
  
  FROM SCPOMGR.FCSTPERFSTATIC f
  JOIN SCPOMGR.DMDUNIT d
  ON f.DMDUNIT=d.DMDUNIT

  WHERE f.STARTDATE BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-08-28'
```

If someone may know, I will greatly appreciate your response.

Thank you.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - simplify! [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Is it the "%" sign you are looking for or the correct calculated value in percentage?
Not sure if you are looking for [this](https://database.guide/4-ways-to-convert-a-number-to-a-percentage-in-sql-server-t-sql/).

Comment: Well, I need both 1) Convert the result of a calculation to two decimals from 123. 792013... to just 123.79 and 2) also add a '%' sign to the column.

Comment: Ok, then above provided link will do the work.

Comment: I am not sure I am getting what I need. When I use VARCHAR + CONVERT to my calculation for some reason i just get NULL values everywhere.

Comment: I basically need to add VARCHAR + CONVERT to this calculation f.TOTHIST / (f.TOTFCST - f.TOTHIST)  - 1 AS 'Sales VS FCST'  to get a result in % with 2 decimal points.

Comment: ` DECLARE @VAL1 VARCHAR(20), @VAL2 VARCHAR(20)
SET @VAL1 = '25.648'
SET @VAL2 = '34.254'
SELECT FORMAT((CONVERT(FLOAT, @VAL1) / (CONVERT(FLOAT, @VAL2) - CONVERT(FLOAT, @VAL1)) - 1), 'P') `

Comment: I think you are looking for something like this.

Comment: Do you mean I need to have smth like this? FORMAT((CONVERT(FLOAT, f.TOTHIST) / (CONVERT(FLOAT, f.TOTFCST) - (CONVERT(FLOAT, f.TOTHIST))  - 1)   when i do it i get an error "incorrect syntax"

Comment: Yes, but you are missing some part of the "Format" function " , 'P') "

Comment: I am not sure I understand. If I add a P i get the error. If I type this one FORMAT((CONVERT(FLOAT, f.TOTHIST) / (CONVERT(FLOAT, f.TOTFCST) - (CONVERT(FLOAT, f.TOTHIST))  - 1), 'P')   I get 'An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.'  As for the declare statement, I am not sure what do you want me to do with them. I don't think I need to assign variables in order just to get % and round the number.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.